# VB replacing an object in a list

Tags: vb.net, list

I have 2 lists approvedSuppliers and originalSupplierData

When approved Suppliers gets populated we clone the entry into the originalSupplierData . If they have modified a record but don't save we ask the user if they want to revert the changes . If they want to revert I am trying to replace the entry in approved suppliers with a clone of the original data. My current code for the revert is

```
    Public Sub RevertChanges(SupplierID As Integer)

    Dim orignalSupplier As Approved_Supplier = originalSupplierlist.Where(Function(x) x.ID = SupplierID).Single()
    Dim modifiedSupplier As Approved_Supplier = ApprovedSuppliers.Where(Function(x) x.ID = SupplierID).Single()

    modifiedSupplier = orignalSupplier.Clone


End Sub
```

The modifiedSupplier gets updated with the original values however the actual item in the list is not updated with the values. 
If I modify one of the properties the list gets update. I am not sure what i am doing wrong can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Edit 
The code for populating the list from the database is

```
        supplierTableAdapter.Fill(supplierTable)

    _approvedSuppliers = New List(Of Approved_Supplier)
    originalSupplierlist = New List(Of Approved_Supplier)()

    For Each row As ApprovedSuppliersDataset.ApprovedSupplierRow In supplierTable
        supplier = New Approved_Supplier()

        supplier.supplierID = row.PLSupplierAccountID
        supplier.AccountNumber = row.SupplierAccountNumber
        supplier.SupplierName = row.SupplierAccountName
        supplier.SupplierAddress = CompileAddress(row)
        supplier.Phone = CompilePhoneNumber(row)

        If row.IsIDNull = False Then

            supplier.ID = row.ID

            If row.IsAdded_ByNull = False Then
                supplier.AddedBy = row.Added_By
            End If

            If row.IsApprovedNull = False Then
                supplier.Approved = row.Approved
            End If

            If row.IsAuditorNull = False Then
                supplier.Auditor = row.Auditor
            End If

            If row.IsAudit_CommentsNull = False Then
                supplier.AuditComments = row.Audit_Comments
            End If

            If row.IsAudit_DateNull = False Then
                supplier.AuditDate = row.Audit_Date
            End If

            If row.IsDate_AddedNull = False Then
                supplier.DateAdded = row.Date_Added
            End If

            If row.IsNotesNull = False Then
                supplier.Notes = row.Notes
            End If

            If row.IsQuestionnaire_Return_DateNull = False Then
                supplier.QuestionnaireReturnDate = row.Questionnaire_Return_Date
            End If

            If row.IsQuestionnaire_Sent_DateNull = False Then
                supplier.QuestionnaireSentDate = row.Questionnaire_Sent_Date
            End If

            If row.IsQuestionnaire_StatusNull = False Then
                supplier.QuestionnaireStatus = row.Questionnaire_Status
            End If

            If row.IsReplinNull = False Then
                supplier.Replin = row.Replin
            End If

            If row.IsReview_CommentsNull = False Then
                supplier.ReviewComment = row.Review_Comments
            End If

            If row.IsReview_DateNull = False Then
                supplier.ReviewDate = row.Review_Date
            End If

            If row.IsReviewerNull = False Then
                supplier.Reviewers = row.Reviewer
            End If

            If row.IsStakeholder_ContactNull = False Then
                supplier.StakeholderContact = row.Stakeholder_Contact
            End If

            If row.IsStandardsNull = False Then
                supplier.Standards = row.Standards
            End If

            If row.IsStandard_ExpiryNull = False Then
                supplier.StandardExpiry = row.Standard_Expiry
            End If

            If row.IsStatusNull = False Then
                supplier.Status = row.Status
            End If

            If row.IsSupplier_Expiry_DateNull = False Then
                supplier.SupplierExpiryDate = row.Supplier_Expiry_Date
            End If

            If row.IsSupplier_ScopeNull = False Then
                supplier.SupplierScope = row.Supplier_Scope
            End If

            If row.Is_T_CsNull = False Then
                supplier.TC = row._T_Cs
            End If
        End If

        supplier.ClearISDirty()
        _approvedSuppliers.Add(supplier)
        originalSupplierlist.Add(supplier.Clone)
    Next
```

and for the clone we have

```
  Public Function Clone() As Object Implements ICloneable.Clone
    Dim cloned As New Approved_Supplier()

    cloned.ID = Me.ID
    cloned.DateAdded = Me.DateAdded
    cloned.Status = Me.Status
    cloned.AddedBy = Me.AddedBy
    cloned.Approved = Me.Approved
    cloned.AuditDate = Me.AuditDate
    cloned.Auditor = Me.Auditor
    cloned.AuditComments = Me.AuditComments
    cloned.QuestionnaireStatus = Me.QuestionnaireStatus
    cloned.QuestionnaireSentDate = Me.QuestionnaireSentDate
    cloned.QuestionnaireReturnDate = Me.QuestionnaireReturnDate
    cloned.ReviewDate = Me.ReviewDate
    cloned.Reviewers = Me.Reviewers
    cloned.ReviewComment = Me.ReviewComment
    cloned.Standards = Me.Standards
    cloned.StandardExpiry = Me.StandardExpiry
    cloned.SupplierScope = Me.SupplierScope
    cloned.Replin = Me.Replin
    cloned.TC = Me.TC
    cloned.Notes = Me.Notes
    cloned.StakeholderContact = Me.StakeholderContact
    cloned.SupplierExpiryDate = Me.SupplierExpiryDate

    cloned.supplierID = Me.supplierID 
    cloned.AccountNumber = Me.AccountNumber
    cloned.SupplierName = Me.SupplierName
    cloned.SupplierAddress = Me.SupplierAddress
    cloned.Phone = Me.Phone
    cloned.Email = Me.Email
    cloned.ClearISDirty()
    Return cloned

End Function
```

Comment: "the actual item in the list is not updated with the values" - what causes the values to be shown?

Comment: Can you show the code used to create the elements in the _originalSupplierList_? And the code used in the Clone method for your _Approved_Supplier_ class?

Comment: You code cannot work because the Clone create a new Object and when you assign the reference of the new object to the variable _modifiedSupplier_ you are changing the reference stored by that variable but you are not changing the reference stored in the _originalSupplierList_ The answer below is correct, you need to change directly the reference stored in the list and not going through an intermediate variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not replacing in the list by affecting modifiedSupplier.

Try by getting the index of the modifiedSupplier and then replacing the item at the found index by your clone.

```
Public Sub RevertChanges(SupplierID As Integer)

    Dim orignalSupplier As Approved_Supplier = originalSupplierlist.Where(Function(x) x.ID = SupplierID).Single()
    Dim modifiedIndex As Integer = ApprovedSuppliers.FindIndex(Function(x) x.ID = SupplierID)

    ApprovedSuppliers(modifiedIndex) = orignalSupplier.Clone()


End Sub
```

Comment: Just tried this and the list still isn't getting updating. I think i may have to go down the refactoring route and update the individual properties individually

Comment: To make sure I understood : The user modify properties on suppliers in the Approved list and it can be reverted. When reverting, you call RevertChanges on all SupplierID modified ? How do you saves thoses IDs ?

Comment: Seeing the code for the Clone method I think that this is correct and should work

Comment: The scenario goes along the lines 
User changes details for a supplier they then move onto the next supplier if they haven't saved they are prompted to save or revert . 
On the revert it pass back to the method the Supplier ID (Unique for the supplier) of the one they have edited it then replaces the modified version with the clone with the original data.

Comment: Are your properties value or reference types ? By example, if Email is a string, your clone effectively copy the string to the other supplier. But if you created a class "Email" then you are affecting the same Email reference to your clone. In this case, you must clone Email (etc) too

Comment: Turns out a subsequent change was causing interference with the update. Instead of updating via the public property for the list i have put it on the private list and that is updating accordingly . Thanks for your help